# POST ing to Sentry using Postman

Tags: postman, sentry

I am trying to reverse engineer how to call Sentry server using Postman. I'm using this https://blog.sentry.io/2017/11/28/sentry-bash article to POST to sentry using CLI, however I am unable to make it work using a simple POST request using Postman. We're trying to POST to sentry from our Mulesoft service using POST API calls so trying to avoid using a Java SDK in between. If I can figure out how to send a request using Postman, I can easily convert it to Mule API call.

Considering that the cli works with only providing the DSN, I am pretty sure we can authenticate using just the DSN. The command on https://docs.sentry.io/api/auth/ is failing however and getting an Unauthorized:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: DSN {DSN}' https://sentry.io/api/0/projects/
```

Answer (score 1):

Sentry document how to create events and their payloads here:

https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/overview/

It covers the protocol and other considerations when building a client library.

Authentications is covered [here](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/overview/#authentication).

Take into account that Sentry develops and maintains [a huge number of client libraries already](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/) so maybe what you're looking for is already there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to generate tokens in order to make a request.  While generating the token, you can choose from the checkboxes according to the authorization groups.
[https://docs.sentry.io/product/integrations/integration-platform/#permissions](https://docs.sentry.io/api/auth/)

After creating the token, you can follow the document below and complete the authentication process.
[Authentication Process](https://docs.sentry.io/api/auth/)

And finally, you can send the requests you want using the api reference document.
[Sentry API reference document](https://docs.sentry.io/api/)